# Operations on Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int> >

Tags: c#

Can someone summarize the following operations, I'm new to c#

1. Adding a keyvaluepair to the dictionary that is a value of `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string,int>>`
2. Getting a keyvalue pair of `Dictionar<string,int>` that is a value of `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<string,int>>`, check if it's empty or null
3. Adding a dictionary "value" to `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string,int>>`

Comment: Real time -1 without commenting is offensive. You're too lazy.

Comment: There is a good chance that you are getting downvotes due to asking question that covered in documentation/should be immediately clear if you tried to write code. Consider instead asking the same in form of  something like "here is my code that should be doing ..... but instead I'm getting .... when using `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int> >`, same code for `Dictionary<int, string >` works fine...".

Comment: Note that there is no requirement (or even encouragement) to live comments for downvotes. You an discuss it on META, but start with reading [Require comments explaining downvotes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question) post before creating your own post.

Comment: Seriously SOF should change the policy of negating the questions. As I said I'm beginner in c#, so there are excuses, otherwise you're free to negate my questions if my reputation is over a threshold that shows that I can't ask a silly question like the one above.

Comment: If you disagree/need clarification with policies/guidances on SO - please feel free to post on [META](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) instead .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you have a generic type as one of the type parameters doesn't change much. In order:

1. `myDict.Add(1, new Dictionary<string, int>());`
2. `var testDict = myDict[1]; if (testDict.Count == 0) if (testDict == null)`
3. `myDict[1].Add("Bob", 2);`

Basically the value is a dictionary. Nothing special about that, just create and treat it like a dictionary.

Comment: but I need to get a keyvaluepair. and add a keyvalue pair to the 2nd dictionary parameter.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ok. Still nothing special. Could you post the code that you *think* should work but doesn't?

Comment: I'm just getting a keypair out of a dictionary, but I don't know how to return a default keypair if I can't get it of the dictionary.

Comment: @Mahmoud There is no "Default Key Pair" indexing into something that doesn't exist will throw. IIRC there is a `Try` version of this out there, but that still doesn't have a "default" keypair, its just null if it fails. If I understand you correctly, you can't have what you are asking for.

Comment: So you can test null for keyvaluepair? I doubt.. how would you test if the returned keypair is valid?

Comment: @Mahmoud You can certainly test if the value is null off of a valid key. If you give a key not present, you will get an exception. This is something you can do with any variant of a Dictionary (as long as the value is nullable).